# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\sqrt {kn}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

I'm not sure which would be the best way to compute this limit. As you might have observed, if you expand the infinite sum and rearrange some terms you get:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt n}{n}\!\cdot\!\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt k$$

it is easy to see that when you take the limit it yields to an indetermination of the type: $$\mathrm{0}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\infty}$$ which you can easily transform into one of the type: $$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$ by dividing by the opposite:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt k}{\frac{n}{\sqrt n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt k}{\sqrt n} $$

I don't know if using L'Hôpital is valid here (as there is an infinite sum in the numerator), how ever, if you differentiate both numerator and denominator, all the square roots in the numerator will go away (except for $\sqrt n$) because they are just constants and you will be left with:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt n} =\lim_{n\to \infty} 1 = 1$$

Is this result correct? I don't even know if it is possible to take the limit of an infinite sum which is not an integral as you are taking discreet steps instead continuous ones.

Thank you for everything.

Comment: what about the term $\sqrt{n-1}$?

Comment: that is one of the facts which made me think that taking the limit of an infinite sum was not possible if the sum couldn't be turned into an integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), you have\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt k&\approx\frac12(\sqrt1+\sqrt n)+\int_1^n \sqrt x\,dx\\&=\frac12+\frac12\sqrt n+\frac23n^{3/2}-\frac23\\&=\frac12\sqrt n+\frac23n^{3/2}-\frac16\end{align}and therefore\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt k&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12+\frac23n-\frac1{6\sqrt n}\\&=\infty.\end{align}

Comment: Could you please mention where the approximation of the sum (1st line) came from.....or if it is a well known relation, what is its name so I can read on it?

Comment: @SaketGurjar I used the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos why did you change the approximately equal sign to an equal sign (from line 1 to 2) ? Thank you very much again.

Comment: @FernandoRuizMazo Well… it's an equality, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, I didn't realized you were in fact developing the right hand side of the equality, however when you finally substitute (last line) you are assuming that $\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt k$ is in fact equal to $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt n+\frac{2}{3}n^{3/2}-\frac{1}{6}$. Is this because you are taking the limit as n approaches infinity?

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}$

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{n}}\frac{√k}{√n} \gt n \dfrac{1}{√n}=√n$;

Take the limit.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (1) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{k} $$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{n}} $$

$$\sqrt{n} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\sqrt{kn}}{n}$$

Now take limit.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\sqrt{kn}}{n}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\sqrt{kn}}{n} =\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\sqrt {\frac{k}{n}} }  \to \int_0^1 {\sqrt x dx}  = \frac{2}{3}.
$$

Comment: I was about to post the hint: "Riemann sum" but you bet me to it.  We should note, however, that the factor $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$$ currently in the problem is not the one that leads to a Riemann sum.

Comment: How does this help solve the question?....i.e. how would you invoke this integral into the question?

Comment: It is shown that the sum in question is asymptotic to $\frac{2}{3} n$ for large $n$.